# Kafka Streams: Notify the stream threads/tasks upon shutdown

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is it possible upon receiving the shutdown signal (kill) we can send a notification to the stream threads, so it can perform the custom activities before the stream.close() is being invoked.

Comment: What do you mean by "perform custom activities"?

Comment: In each partition thread we maintain a hashset and results of that should be written to the file before shutdown

Comment: Why do you not maintain the hashset in a state store?